# two classes have vector of pointers to each

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Hi I want to make a code for 2D mesh. I have two classes vertex and element. Each vertex should have a vector of pointers to the neighbour elements. Also each element should have a vector of pointers tot the neighbour vertices. I did that. However, when I try to access the neighbours some time I get incorrect results.
Here is my listing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A;
struct B;

struct A
{
    vector<B*> vbs;
    A(int aa)
    {
        a=aa;
    }
    int a;
};

struct B
{
    vector<A*> vas;
    B(int bb)
    {
        b=bb;
    }
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> VA;
    vector<B> VB;
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        VA.push_back(A(i));
        VB.push_back(B(10-i));

        VA.back().vbs.push_back(&VB.back());
        VB.back().vas.push_back(&VA.back());
    }
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        cout<<"A["<< i<<"]= "<<VA[i].a 
        <<" :::: " <<VA[i].vbs.size() <<" :: " <<VA[i].vbs[0]->b <<endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        cout<<"B["<< i<<"]= " <<VB[i].b
        <<" :::: " <<VB[i].vas.size() <<" :: " <<VB[i].vas[0]->a  <<endl;
    }
}
```

This is a minimal example for my case
The results from ideone.com is

```
A[0]= 0 :::: 1 :: 10
A[1]= 1 :::: 1 :: 9
A[2]= 2 :::: 1 :: -1216846712
A[3]= 3 :::: 1 :: -1216846728
A[4]= 4 :::: 1 :: 6
A[5]= 5 :::: 1 :: 5
A[6]= 6 :::: 1 :: 4
A[7]= 7 :::: 1 :: 3
A[8]= 8 :::: 1 :: 2
A[9]= 9 :::: 1 :: 1
A[10]= 10 :::: 1 :: 0
B[0]= 10 :::: 1 :: 0
B[1]= 9 :::: 1 :: 1
B[2]= 8 :::: 1 :: 17
B[3]= 7 :::: 1 :: 17
B[4]= 6 :::: 1 :: 193
B[5]= 5 :::: 1 :: 5
B[6]= 4 :::: 1 :: 6
B[7]= 3 :::: 1 :: 7
B[8]= 2 :::: 1 :: 8
B[9]= 1 :::: 1 :: 9
B[10]= 0 :::: 1 :: 10
```

as you notice A[2],A[3],B[2],B[3], and B[4] are incorrect
what I am doing wrong. is it possible this is a bug in the compiler

regards

Comment: You did not specify what compiler do you use. Assuming it's something mainline (GCC, Clang, MSCV), a bug is always possible, but highly unlikely in such a simple code.

Comment: `is it possible this is a bug in the compiler`  There is no bug in the compiler.  See answers below as to what the issue is.

Comment: replace std::vector by std::deque to avoid reallocations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the size of a vector invalidates iterators, therefore pointers to the vector's elements can possibly be invalidated here:

```
    VA.back().vbs.push_back(&VB.back());
    VB.back().vas.push_back(&VA.back())
```

If you're doing anything like this, reconsider your design. Storing pointers to elements in a vector is a dangerous road to take.

Some solutions were given in the other answers.  Another probable solution is to use a `std::list` instead of `vector`, as a `list` iterators are not invalidated (only if the items from the list is removed is the iterator invalidated for the removed item).

Another solution would be to call the vector's `reserve()` with the maximum number of items expected.  But even this is shaky in the event that the vector's item count exceeds the reserved amount.  Better to rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after some of the `push_back` calls, the pointers you took before become invalid, because the vector class needs to reallocate the data. That involves allocating a new block of memory and moving the objects.

You can solve the problem by doing it in two steps, first populate the vectors and only after that take pointers, or you can store indexes rather than pointers, or use `vector<A*>` with dynamic allocation instead of `vector<A>`.